# How can I bind active class to the first element from loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I add
`isTypeSelected(dietType)`

to be default for the first element from v-for list?

```
b-col(lg="" md="6", sm="6").text-center(v-for="dietType in dietTypeList", :key="dietType.id")
    div.pointer(:class="{ faded: !isTypeSelected(dietType) }", @click.prevent="dietTypeId = dietType.id")
      dbm-icon.p-2.diet-type-icon(:icon="dietType.icon", variant="secondary", v-if="isTypeSelected(dietType)")
      dbm-icon.p-2.diet-type-icon(:icon="dietType.icon", variant="light", v-if="!isTypeSelected(dietType)")
      p {{ dietType.name }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `&& dietType.id===1`  to the class binding condition :

```
 div.pointer(:class="{ faded: !isTypeSelected(dietType) && dietType.id===1 }"
```

Comment: I got one more question, can I bind a state to this?
When I do ```:v-bind="dietTypeId = dietType.id"``` , I am not able to choose other buttons.

Comment: No, try to add `dietTypeId ` to your data property initialized with 1 then update in the click event

Comment: dietTypeId is computed property  ```get() {
        return this.firstLogin.dietTypeId;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.setDietTypeId(value);
        this.fetchProducts();
      },
    },```

So I think I cant add to data dietTypeId

Comment: try to add another one

Comment: Tried ```@click.prevent="dietTypeId = dietActive"``` added dietActive to data with value 1
Im getting error, ```{"for_diet_type_id":["invalid"]}```

Comment: I mean it's checked at start, but when I switch, then try to click it again i get the error

Comment: Try to add another property in data called `currentDiet` with 1 at start and `div.pointer(:class="{ faded: !isTypeSelected(dietType) && dietType.id===currentDiet }"` and update it in the click event